# My note 3 will not mount on to my computer

Tags: usb, samsung-galaxy-note-3

I used to plug it in, and it would show up and I could download the pictures and movies and such. Today, it will not mount. It is charging from the computer, but I can not download any of the stuff I've done.

Running windows 7 on my computer.

I've turned it off and on again, it is not working.

I probably have added an app or two, I am not sure. It has been a while since I uploaded from this phone, but I plug it into the computer every night. Is it possible I accidentally hit a tick box and instructed it not to mount?

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts, Daniel! We will need a few more details in order to be able to help you: Anything changed since it worked last time (settings, new apps)? And the old IT question: "Have you turned it off and on again?" Sometimes things get stuck, so a reboot might help.

Comment: Also: have you tried connecting your Galaxy Note 3 to another computer, if any? Have you tried with a different (but compatible, of course) USB cable, if any?

Comment: You probably don't have the correct Samsung USB drivers for Windows 7. Download the USB drivers, install it, plug in your Samsung Galaxy Note 3 and let Windows install the appropriate drivers to allow your device to connect seamlessly with Windows.

Answer (score 1):

What operating system do you run on your computer? That sometimes happened to me when I used Windows. Have you tried using [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid), though? I use that now. It basically does remotely, what you would do with a USB.

But that's just an alternative, I'll wait for your response to see if maybe I have a solution.

Comment: Indeed, this is a good emergency solution if what you need is to transfer files between your computer and your device with some urgency.

Comment: Yes, it is, haha. Is this not what you were trying to do, though? Because you have cross-file browsing and sending SMS, accessing camera, Gallery and more. But have you tried another cable? Or maybe mount settings in Android?

Comment: I know the requirements, but you don't need the same network now, only "any" type of network connection. But that just uses up more carrier data.

Comment: Well this isn't an FAQ per say, but try: http://airdroid.com/download/ I'm trying to find the FAQ as well.

Comment: **Computer requirements:** There is no need to install any software or drivers on your PC/Mac though - an existing web browser (Google Chrome, Firefox, Safari) is enough. [Source: Install AirDroid](http://help.airdroid.com/customer/portal/articles/1289502-install-airdroid). (This info is from Oct 15, 2013)

Comment: The Questioner submitted an edit to your answer stating that they run Windows 7.  I presume they were trying to add a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I solved similar problems by installing [Samsung Kies](http://www.samsung.com/de/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/JSP) on my Laptop (Windows 7). It installed all drivers that couldn't be found using Windows Update.